# xml files are downloaded in the wrong format

Tags: c#, xml, download, identityserver3

we have a web application in `C#` where our users can download `.xml` files but since we introduced identity server3 in our new update our download intermittently stop working and some early access users reported that they are (2 times on 3) downloading `authorise.htm` and/or a file without a format extension (that if renamed has all the content) and so on.

What part of our system is likely to be causing it? I'm a tester so I'm not expert in debugging but I am trying to understand what are our suspects.

Could it be some configuration issue? firewall issues?

Comment: Have a look at what has changed. If the error occurs after introducing Identity Server 3, it might have something to do with it. If configuration and firewall haven't changed, chances of them being the cause are slim.

Comment: actually they have changed, we used a port in test environment and we have changed it for our early access. I understand from my programmer that we should have rectified this by now but still...

Comment: The headers in the http messages have changed.  A default setting on old server is different on new server.  One possibility is the new server is using http 1.1 instead of http 1.0.   http 1.1 doesn't work with the Net Library.  The best way of debugging issue is to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to capture the http messages from client to server.  Can be downloaded for free.  Then compare headers using old server with headers on new server.

Comment: I didn't see nothing obviously wrong or different when I used Fiddler, however every bad download generates a nonce. When I am inactive for a few minutes and I issue a download it goes wrong (and generates a nonce), if I refresh the page it works